# Extract number before and after character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to extract a certain number from my 'TblA' from column 'Input' in sql.
I have the following example input and desired output 1 and 2.

| Input | Desired Output 1 | Desired Output 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 x 88 nc. | 20 | 88 |
| 100 x 300 nc | 100 | 300 |
| 200x 88 nc. | 200 | 88 |
| 5x 300 nc | 5 | 300 |
| ol (200x 88nc.) | 200 | 88 |
| ol (100x 300nc) | 100 | 300 |
| 90dfa (45x65) | 45 | 65 |
| 90dfa (45 x 65) | 45 | 65 |
| 5,5 x 30 nc | 5,5 | 30 |
| 5.5 x 30 nc | 5.5 | 30 |

Could you please help me with this code?
Thank you in advance.
I have worked in the past with Left and right functions to the the Nth character.
But I don't know where to start with this code.
I am using sql server 2019

Comment: *"I tried to work with string replace, but this is not working."* And what was that attempt? You forgot to include it in your question. Show us that attempt, so we can see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one `'x'` in your string (as in all your examples), then the following works:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     (select stuff(col1, 1, len(col1) - patindex('%[^0-9,.]%', reverse(col1) + ' ') + 1, '') as col1,
             left(col2, patindex('%[^0-9,.]%', col2 + ' ') - 1) as col2
      from (values (replace(left(t.input, charindex('x', t.input) - 1), ' ', ''),
                    replace(stuff(t.input, 1, charindex('x', t.input), ''), ' ', '')
                   ) 
           ) v(col1, col2)
     ) v;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf8a4d5c32f59e7fda24ca6b2a658cc6) is a db<>fiddle.